# Join branch into new master commit without merging?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I have 2 branches: `master` and `mybranch`
the `mybranch` is based on an old `master` commit and I'd like *move* it to a new `master` commit without merging into `master`.

The hierarchy tree currently look like this:

```
master[commit1]---[commit2]---[commit3]---[commit4]
          |
          |
       mybranch[commit1]---[commit2]
```

I'd like it to be like this:

```
master[commit1]---[commit2]---[commit3]---[commit4]
          |                                   |
          |                                   |
       mybranch[commit1]---[commit2]       mybranch[commit3]---[commit4]
```

Here is a screenshot from Sourcetree:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want to rebase

Comment: I've tried rebase (checkout master then `git rebase mybranch`) and after at lot of conflict files it just showed `mybranch` as lastest commit (on top of the tree) but still coming out of old  `master` commit

Comment: Try the other way round `git checkout mybranch; git rebase master`

Answer (score 5):

When trying to understand and manipulate git branch trees, it's important to know that branches are a pointer to the *most recent* commit in a particular lineage, and history is traced *back* from there. Older commits don't "belong to" a particular branch, they are just reachable in its history.

So your actual tree looks like this (I've renamed the two commits you called `commit1` to `commit_1` and `commit_b1`; this is one of the reasons git commits are referenced by hashes, not sequential IDs!):

```
           +---[commit_2]---[commit_3]---[commit_4] <-- master
           |
[commit_1]-+
           |
           +-- [commit_b1]---[commit_b2] <-- mybranch
```

If you redraw the tree you asked for in the same way, it will look like this:

```
                                           master
                                             |
                                             v
           +---[commit_2]---[commit_3]---[commit_4]---[commit_b3]---[commit_b4] <-- mybranch
           |
[commit_1]-+
           |
           +-- [commit_b1]---[commit_b2] <-- ???
```

There is no relationship between commits b1 and b2 on one hand, and b3 and b4 on the other. The branch pointer "mybranch" can't point to both of them, unless it points to a new commit that merges them together.

However, that may be what you wanted: you talk about "moving" the branch, which is [what `git rebase` does](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase). More accurately, it *copies* the commits, creating new commits that look like them, so commit b3 will be a copy of b1 and b4 a copy of b2. (The original b1 and b2 commits, which are now unreachable by any branch pointer, will eventually be garbage collected.)

The most explicit form of `git rebase` requires you to specify three points in history - usually branch names, but can be anything that identifies a particular commit:

```
git rebase --onto <new-parent> <old-parent> <branch>
```

It means "take all the commits from `<old-parent>` up to and including the current tip of `<branch>`, recreate them on top of `<new-parent>`, and point `<branch>` at the last of these new commits".

In common scenarios, you can specify fewer arguments:

```
git rebase <parent> <branch>
```

This means "take all the commits that are reachable from `<branch>`, but not from `<parent>`; recreate them on top of the current tip of `<parent>`, and point `<branch>` at the result.

```
git rebase <parent>
```

This is the same as above, but it uses the currently checked out branch as `<branch>`.

So in your case, any of the following should produce the same result:

```
git rebase --onto master commit_1 mybranch
git rebase master mybranch
git switch mybranch; git rebase master
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. In my case there are conflict commits needs to be resolved. Do I need use `git add` or `git rm` to resolve them? I really don't care at what stage the code in mybranch ends up with.

Comment: @vanowm Have a look for some tutorials on how to resolve git conflicts. They're often easier in a graphical tool, and there's lots of different scenarios, so it's not something that can be answered in a quick comment.

Comment: I basically did `git rm <file>` for all conflicts, it worked, but the branch ended up with bunch of pull and push numbers, and I just push force it to remote and it worked very well for the next commit to that branch.